# Setting UrlSegmentMaxLength from commadline

Tags: iis, appcmd, http.sys

Is there a way to set the `UrlSegmentMaxLength` value for `Http.sys` using appcmd/netsh or any other commandline utility?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but in case someone stumbles upon this, here's PowerShell one-liner that either creates the key and sets the value or updates existing value.

```
if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 2048 -PropertyType DWord } else { Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 2048 }
```

`

As for restarting, I found that this works well (no need to restart the server):

```
Stop-Service http -Force
Start-Service http
Start-Service IISADMIN
Start-Service W3SVC
```

Answer (score 1):

I change this for my deployment in powershell
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 500
Restart-Service W3SVC -Force

Comment: I realized that it's not the W3SVC that needs to be restarted, but the HTTP service.  You can try calling "net stop http" and "net start http" after the reg change, but I've found restarting to be more reliable.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amyd/archive/2014/02/06/response-400-bad-request-on-long-url.aspx