# Not able to use string over 260 characters as a segment of URL in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2, kestrel-http-server

I'm making a request that works great and acts as supposed to. The actual authorization is provided using headers and working as expected too. This is the URL of it.

> https://localhost:44385/api/security/check

By coincidence, I happened to replace the verbatim string *check* with the actual token, so the URL changed to

> https://localhost:44385/api/security/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ...

All in all, the token happens to be 475 characters long. Then, when executing that call, I get the error message as follows.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44300

I don't understand the issue and the status code 400 tells me only that the request is bad. Is it purely due ot the length of the URL? It seems like a bit too short (although there is a limitation for that but we're talking about a few thousands characters)...

The signature of the receiving method in the controller looks like this. It resides in the controller with path *Security*.

```
[HttpHead("{check}"), Authorize]
public IActionResult IsAuthorized(string check) { ... }
```

I also tried GET instead of HEAD with the same result. It's difficult to learn more about the error based on *400 Bad request* only. It's a bit like *something went wrong somewhere* kind of error.

After some experimenting, I can confirm that it's **not** the length of the URL as such but rather the length of the segment between slashes. The first request works, the other does too but the third doesn't. The *xxx* part is precisely 260 characters and **yyy* part is precisely 261.

> https://localhost:44385/api/test/xxx
>   https://localhost:44385/api/testtest/xxx
>   https://localhost:44385/api/test/yyy

What is this about?! It's like `string` in a method in my WebAPI can't be longer than 260 characters. Not 256, which at least would make some kind of sense...

Googling gave a **veeery** wide range of vastly spread hits and gave me nothing that I could relate to. Postman provides pretty much the same, limited information. The browser's network tab give even less.

A bit confused how to get to know more, how to diagnose it further and/or what to google for. Since it's a non-problem for the production environment, I can't bother my colleagues - the question is purely academic.

Comment: I don't think there's anything we can do without seeing the action method signatures.

Comment: @DavidG I posted the method, as requested. Please bear in mind that it does work for a shorter string and that I tested it both for HEAD and GET to exclude the risk of something unfamiliar to me hiding there.

Comment: @robertperry It must have gotten mixed up while experimenting with different approaches while figuring out what the issue was, my bad, sorry about that. Also, for the record, I didn't donvote (I very rarely do). As for your suggestion - yes, that needs to match. The issue isn't with the signature or binding. For some reason, the argument passed in must not exceed 260 character, seemingly. And I can't find any info about such restriction in MSDN...

Comment: Do you have the static files middleware enabled? If so, can you remove it?

Comment: @DavidG Apparently it was an obscure property nobody's heard about (maybe except for the user who answered below). Talking about a sneaky gotcha...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The limit you're hitting is `UrlSegmentMaxLength` (260).
>
> This is all the way down in `Http.Sys` and only configurable in the
>   registry.
>
> - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows
>
> Workaround: break it up into multiple path segments, or move it to the
>   query or body. Or use Kestrel without IIS.

Resource: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2823#issuecomment-360921436

---

Here's a related post:

- [Setting UrlSegmentMaxLength from commadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376134/setting-urlsegmentmaxlength-from-commadline)

Comment: It is **not** the most commonly known feature of web development. I've been putting bugs in the software professionally in over 13 years and this is the first time I hear about it (as far I recall). I've never needed to exceed the limitation nor do I expect to need. But it bothers me now, that I became aware of it, that I'm restricted, haha. Pragmatically speaking it's a non-issue because I pasted in the token by mistake. Great answer!