# weird error 400 bad request with not-so-long parameter

Tags: php, redirect, iis, server

I have a problem where a not so long url parameter causes a

`Bad Request - Invalid URL. HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`

Here is a sample that throws the error (param2 is 415 bytes long):

```
https://www.example.com/folder/sub/myword&param2=fsadifsdifhsidufhsdiufhieruwhfierfhiurefhierfheriofheriufheriufheriufheriufrehiufherfierhffsaidfsdiufhsdiufshduifsduifsdhfuidssafsdfdsfdsfsdfdsfdsfadsfdsfdsasfsdufsduyfgdsuyfgduysfgdysufgudsfdsufdsfsdfasdfsdiofjdosifjodsifjoisdfjsdoifjdosifjosdifjsdoifjdsoifjodsifjodsifjsdfdsufidshufhiuhiuerfhreuifhreuifhreuifhreuifhreiufhreiufhreifurehfuireihfurefhreifhureifhreuifhreiufhreiufhureifhruiefreuifheruifwheiurfhruie
```

but if I explicitly set `index.php?word=myword&param2=blabla...` in the path, this works perfectly well:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/sub/index.php?word&param2=fsadifsdifhsidufhsdiufhieruwhfierfhiurefhierfheriofheriufheriufheriufheriufrehiufherfierhffsaidfsdiufhsdiufshduifsduifsdhfuidssafsdfdsfdsfsdfdsfdsfadsfdsfdsasfsdufsduyfgdsuyfgduysfgdysufgudsfdsufdsfsdfasdfsdiofjdosifjodsifjoisdfjsdoifjdosifjosdifjsdoifjdsoifjodsifjodsifjsdfdsufidshufhiuhiuerfhreuifhreuifhreuifhreuifhreiufhreiufhreifurehfuireihfurefhreifhureifhreuifhreiufhreiufhureifhruiefreuifheruifwheiurfhruie
```

here is the web.config that redirects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Friendly">
                    <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?word={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

now, if `param2` is shorter, up to 246 bytes, or total 252 bytes (with the first parameter's length), there is no problem at all, which seems weird. Screenshot:

[image]

Things i've checked and didn't help:

- `Maximum URL length` and `Maximum query string` are both set to 32768 bytes (32KB) in IIS Request Filtering
- I do `var_dump($_GET);` in index.php and i still get the bad request error
- I enabled Failed Request Tracing and I get nothing in the logs
- I tried both `true` and `false` for `appendQueryString`

I'm not sure what else to do. Web server is IIS 8.5 and PHP is 7.4. Any help or ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"Here is a sample that throws the error"_ - is it intentional, that you do not actually have a `?` in there, and are effectively using `&` in the _path_ component of the URL?

Comment: @CBroe yes it's intentional. `https://www.example.com/folder/sub/myword` is synonymous to `https://www.example.com/folder/sub/index.php?word=myword` due to the rule redirection. if that's what you're asking, so after myword, `?` is not needed?. BTW if param2 is shorter, there is no problem at all!

Comment: I am asking about `https://www.example.com/folder/sub/myword&param2=fsad...`, which is your input URL _before_ any rewriting happens, is it not?

Comment: @CBroe yes the lack of `?` there is intentional, it's not needed, as the rewriting will redirect it to `index.php?word=myword&param2=fsad...` and I can tell it's not needed because if param2 is shorter, say 200 bytes, the error does not happen, all goes normally.

Comment: `url="index.php?word={R:1}"` - pretty sure IIS will apply URL encoding to the value of the `word` parameter here, right? In that case, your first URL would _not_ rewrite to the equivalent of `index.php?word=myword&param2=fsad...`. You would get a URL with only _one_ parameter named `word`, and the value of that parameter would be `myword&param2=fsad...`

Comment: @CBroe I'm not entirely sure, is the rule wrong? If so, why I do not get the bad request error, if param2 is shorter and everything else is the same?

Comment: No, I think your input URL is wrong to begin with. The pattern `^(.+)$` will match the whole `myword&param2=fsad...` here. And if you insert that as the value of the `word` parameter, _and_ that value gets URL-encoded in the process - then you end up with `index.php?word=myword%26param2%3Dfsad...` here, which is of course something completely different, than `index.php?word=myword&param2=fsad...` would be. You now only have one single parameter named `word`, and nothing else - no parameter named `param2`

Comment: @CBroe `var_dump($_GET);` on `https://www.example.com/folder/sub/myword&param2=fsadifsdifhsidufhsdiufhier` gets me `array(2) { ["word"]=> string(6) "myword" ["param2"]=> string(26) "fsadifsdifhsidufhsdiufhier" }`. Please note the lack of `?`. So it works well and captures both parameters and doesn't seem to be the issue. I only get the bad request if param2 goes ~350 bytes. Maybe some overflow is possible?

Comment: @CBroe I updated the initial post with a screenshot. Edit: i just noticed that the problem occurs when the total length of both parameters is larger than 252 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could also be that HTTP.sys is not even letting the request through, you can change that setting in the registry, after restarting, try again.

Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters]
"UrlSegmentMaxLength"=dword:00000400
```

This will effectively set the segment length to 1024.

Comment: yes, this is the answer. Thank you. Also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448588/i-get-a-400-bad-request-invalid-url-when-the-length-of-the-request-exceeds-320 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475169/not-able-to-use-string-over-260-characters-as-a-segment-of-url-in-net-core